# why 'ni' goes into function in Android gdb debugging?

Tags: android, gdb

I'm debugging android JNI with gdb without source code. I use `ni` command to step over arm asm instructions. I suppose `ni` is `step over`, but it still goes into function like `BL xxxx`, and I have to use `finish` to get back.

I tried `ni` and `si`, seems no difference, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the source code, so I assume you don't have any debug information with your binary either. This is just a guess, but without them, I suppose your BL is seen as a mere branch, not a subroutine call. For further explanation, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841603/skip-library-function-in-arm-assembly-gdb/18866424#comment27821846_18847660).